# What's a formal way of saying "seems like"?

Tags: grammar

I'm writing a formal essay and I need to use what's equivalent of 〜そうです for "seems like"

Please help
Thanks!

Comment: This question needs to be more specific, you'd provide a complete sentence or couple of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use:

「～～と推測{すいそく}される」

「～～と/～～のように思{おも}われる/思える」

「～～と/～～のように見{み}える」